# How to set View Height dynamiocally based on the android device?

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, view

I have a view and I am measuring screen size of the device dynamically using this method.

```
private double getscreenSize() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    double x = Math.pow(
            ((double) (dm.widthPixels) / (double) (dm.densityDpi)), 2);
    double y = Math.pow(
            ((double) (dm.heightPixels) / (double) (dm.densityDpi)), 2);
    return Math.sqrt(x + y);
}
```

It returns 4.58 inch for both s3 and s4. But in s4 , the view looks too small and in s3 it looks perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code-

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

After getting height and width use this for your view.